# How to automatically re-fetch another query when a query is called?

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I need to update the `getSearchHistory` cache when calling the `getSearch` query.

My First solution come up with adding invalidateTags in query,but the query can't invalidate tag

```
 export const searchApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    search: builder.query<SearchResponseType, SearchRequestType>({
      query: (request) => ({
        url: `${activityBaseUrl}search`,
        method: 'GET',
        params: request,
      }),
      providesTags: [{ type: 'Activity', id: 'List' }],
      // invalidatesTags: ['SearchHistory'] 
      // so that searchHistory can automated re-fetched
      // but got error: endpointDefinitions.d.ts(227, 5): The expected type comes from property 'invalidatesTags' '
    }),
  }),
});
```

```
export const getSearchHistoryApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getSearchHistory: builder.query<SearchHistoryResponse, SearchHistoryRequest>({
      query: (params) => ({
        url: `${userBaseUrl}search/history`,
        method: 'GET',
        params,
      }),
      providesTags: ['SearchHistory'],
    }),
  }),
});
```

Is there any solution that can automate the refetching of `getSearchHistory` when `getSearch` is called?